# Does twitter stream API allow filtering by urls?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to do a filter by urls but no result is being returned.
From the following doc, it shows it is possible https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/premium-operators
but I think it's a premium feature. Is this true? If yes then is there any other way to filter by urls without using the premium feature?

Comment: The [Twitter Developer Labs filtered stream API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/filtered-stream/guides/search-queries) (future version of the Twitter API) supports filtering by URLs. However, it is difficult to know how to answer you because you've not shown us any code, and you've tagged this as both tweepy (Python) and Twitter4J (Java) and currently neither of those libraries support Twitter Developer Labs. If you can improve your question and explain what you're trying to achieve, we can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Twitter streaming API provide us with **'track'** parameter. This is a Standard streaming API parameter (see the [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters)). It matches Tweets as by phrases as by URLs. A common use case according to the doc:

> a common use case where you may want to track all mentions of a particular domain name (i.e., regardless of subdomain or path), you should use “example com” as the track parameter for “example.com”

This parameter value *Will match...*:

> example.comwww.example.com foo.example.com foo.example.com/bar I hope my startup isn’t merely another example of a dot com boom!

I tested the option by means of twitter-hbc library for Java. It works as expected!

To avoid confusion, please, take the note:

> The text of the Tweet and some entity fields are considered for matches. Specifically, the text attribute of the Tweet, expanded_url and display_url for links and media, text for hashtags, and screen_name for user mentions are checked for matches.